# Data is not saved to the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am preparing a booking calendar system using php and mysql, And this system shows the empty hours you want to book. I want to insert data into database, entered in a modal that opened with a clicking any button. But not inserting and how can I solve this problem.

My source codes and screenshot of my PhpMyAdmin panel as follow,

Thanks for answers

```
<?php
$bookings = array();
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bookingcalendar');
if(isset($_GET['date'])){
    $date = $_GET['date'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from bookings where date = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $date);    
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if($result->num_rows>0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $bookings[] = $row['timeslot'];
            }

            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $timeslot = $_POST['timeslot'];
    $room_name = $_POST['room_name'];
    $attendees = $_POST['attendees'];
    $notes = $_POST['notes'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from bookings where date = ? AND timeslot = ? AND room_name = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $date, $timeslot, $room_name);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if($result->num_rows>0){     
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Already Booked</div>";
        }else{
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO bookings (name, timeslot, email, date, room_name, attendees, notes) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $name, $timeslot, $email, $date, $room_name, $attendees, $notes);
            $stmt->execute();
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Booking Successfull</div>";
            $bookings[] = $timeslot;
            $stmt->close();
            $mysqli->close();
        }
    }

}
$duration = 60;
$cleanup = 0;
$start = "08:00";
$end = "18:00";



function timeslots($duration,$cleanup,$start,$end){
    $start = new DateTime($start);
    $end = new DateTime($end);
    $interval = new DateInterval("PT".$duration."M");
    $cleanupInterval = new DateInterval("PT".$cleanup."M");
    $slots = array();

    for($intStart = $start; $intStart<$end; $intStart->add($interval)->add($cleanupInterval)){
        $endPeriod = clone $intStart;
        $endPeriod->add($interval);
        if($endPeriod>$end){
            break;
        }
        $slots[] = $intStart->format("H:iA")."-".$endPeriod->format("H:iA");
    }
    return $slots;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $dt = new DateTime;
        if (isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['week'])) {
            $dt->setISODate($_GET['year'], $_GET['week']);
        } else {
            $dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W'));
        }
        $year = $dt->format('o');
        $week = $dt->format('W');
        $month = $dt->format('F');
        $year = $dt->format('Y');
    ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">               
                <center>
                   <h2><?php echo "$month $year" ?></h2>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week-1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Pre Week</a>
                    <!--Previous week-->
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="index.php">Current Week</a>
                    <!--Curren week-->
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week+1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Next Week</a>
                    <!--Next week-->
                </center>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <?php echo (isset($msg))?$msg:""; ?>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr class="success">
                        <?php
                            do {
                                if($dt->format('d M Y')== date('d M Y')){
                                    echo "<td style='background:yellow'>" . $dt->format('l') . "<br>" . $dt->format('d M Y') . "</td>\n";
                                }else{
                                    echo "<td>" . $dt->format('l') . "<br>" . $dt->format('d M Y') . "</td>\n";
                                }

                                $dt->modify('+1 day');
                            } while ($week == $dt->format('W'));
                        ?>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        $timeslots = timeslots($duration,$cleanup,$start,$end);
                        foreach($timeslots as $ts){
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php if(in_array($ts,$bookings)){?>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger"><?php echo $ts; ?> </button>
                            <?php }
                            else{ ?>
                               <button class="btn btn-success book" data-timeslot="<?php echo $ts; ?>"><?php echo $ts; ?>
                               </button>
                            <?php } ?> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php if(in_array($ts,$bookings)){?>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger"><?php echo $ts; ?> </button>
                            <?php }
                            else{ ?>
                               <button class="btn btn-success book" data-timeslot="<?php echo $ts; ?>"><?php echo $ts; ?>
                               </button>
                            <?php } ?> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php if(in_array($ts,$bookings)){?>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger"><?php echo $ts; ?> </button>
                            <?php }
                            else{ ?>
                               <button class="btn btn-success book" data-timeslot="<?php echo $ts; ?>"><?php echo $ts; ?>
                               </button>
                            <?php } ?> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php if(in_array($ts,$bookings)){?>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger"><?php echo $ts; ?> </button>
                            <?php }
                            else{ ?>
                               <button class="btn btn-success book" data-timeslot="<?php echo $ts; ?>"><?php echo $ts; ?>
                               </button>
                            <?php } ?> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php if(in_array($ts,$bookings)){?>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger"><?php echo $ts; ?> </button>
                            <?php }
                            else{ ?>
                               <button class="btn btn-success book" data-timeslot="<?php echo $ts; ?>"><?php echo $ts; ?>
                               </button>
                            <?php } ?> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php if(in_array($ts,$bookings)){?>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger"><?php echo $ts; ?> </button>
                            <?php }
                            else{ ?>
                               <button class="btn btn-success book" data-timeslot="<?php echo $ts; ?>"><?php echo $ts; ?>
                               </button>
                            <?php } ?> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php if(in_array($ts,$bookings)){?>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger"><?php echo $ts; ?> </button>
                            <?php }
                            else{ ?>
                               <button class="btn btn-success book" data-timeslot="<?php echo $ts; ?>"><?php echo $ts; ?>
                               </button>
                            <?php } ?> 
                        </td>     
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Booking <span id="slot"></span></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Timeslot</label>
                                    <input type="text" redonly name="timeslot" id="timeslot" class="form-control" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Room Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="roomname" class="form-control" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
                                </div>                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Number of attendees</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="attendees" class="form-control" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Reservation notes</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="notes" class="form-control" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group pull-right">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(".book").click(function() {
            var timeslot = $(this).attr('data-timeslot');
            $("#slot").html(timeslot);
            $("#timeslot").val(timeslot);
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[phpmyadmin screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwEIV.jpg)

Comment: 3 placeholders in query, 2 in bind_param.

Comment: The INSERT has 7 placeholders and 'ssss' in bind_param (but 7 values).

Comment: I made some changes but still doesn't work

Comment: "Still doesn't work" is not a very useful problem description.

Comment: That means do no save into database

Comment: Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) along every mysqli step of the way to see what might be going wrong.